# In skyrim, where can I find a ship that is insanely loaded with wine?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard, skyrim-hearthfire

I was randomly exploring skyrim and once came across a ship. I'm not sure whether it was in the DLC (where we go back to morrowind) and then help some guy disable a lighthouse and then capture a ship OR, it might have been some other ship in skyrim.

But here's what the ship looked like:

You enter the ship, kill off all the bandits. Then at the bottom-most layer of the ship, (the "basement" or whatever it is called), there were tons and tons of wine bottles. There were loads and loads of "Mead Barrels" and each had a bunch of meads. I mean the place was completely stacked with wines. There were so many bottles that I could probably conquer the whole skyrim.

Can anyone tell me where I can find that ship? I've been searching for it everywhere but not finding it.

Comment: This sounds like the quest [Lights Out](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lights_Out!), but I'm having a hard time understanding your question. You say you found a ship, but then ask where you can find said ship.

Comment: @Wondercricket I believe he is saying that he found the ship in a previous playthrough, or a long time ago in his current playthrough, but can't remember which ship it was; if the Lights Out quest ship indeed has inordinately large quantities of wine and mead then that's probably the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely referring to [The Red Wave](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Red_Wave). It can be found docked in Solitude, and is part of both the Dainty Sload and Dark Brotherhood quest lines.

[image: The Red Wave in Solitude]

The hold of this pirate vessel is full of empty (and full) wine bottles, as well as many full food barrels.